# Lotus Notes View does not hide the level of details within a column - notes domino designer

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

I have a View in Lotus notes by formula.

The View is as follows  by   Org Exec \ Organization \ Total Headcount

I have a "show twistie when row is expandable" enabled and "Categorized" selected as Type for the column  "Org Exec" & "Organization"

For example data looks like this:  Marshell Rodrigues \ Tester \ 100

However my problem is that tester has the list of 100 people within it and i do not want to show that level of details in the view? I want Organization not to show the list of people within it.

I tried the Hide detail row on the Organization column properties but that does not work it still shows data within the organisation in the view

any ideas or suggestion ?

What is the purpose of the view?

I am trying to Export this View in Excel Using ODBC Connection Thus i want the details at a higher level

What kind of documents are in the database?

Each employee has his record in the database with his details liek organization , execs, headcount name, serial number .

What kind of information should be displayed ?

Like i said the information to be displayed need to be at a high level for example :

Give me All Organization Execs by Organization Total Headcount (i just want the total number i do not want to see a drill down on thoes numbers in the view)

Example if Org "abc" has 10 headcount i just want it to display 10 ... i do not want to see who thoes 10 people are.

and from which docs does the info come from?

All the docs have a fields named Org Execs and Organisation and Headcount(were Headcoutn can be 1 if working and 0 if not working for individual month)

What are the column formulas?

Select form = "xyz" ....

Columns Org Execs \ Organization \ HeadCount (All 3 are fields in each record)

Comment: To answer your question we would need mor information! "Hide detail row" does not work in this place - is only used for columns displaying Totals or Sums. What is the purpose of the view? What kind of documents are in the database? What kind of information should be displayed and from which docs does the info come from? What are the column formulas? ...

Comment: HI Michael i have edited my Question on top due to character limitation and tried to answer your question in details ? Any suggestions ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would call that a "roll-up report", but views in Lotus Notes are not reports.  They are designed to give users access to documents.  Summarizing data (with totals, percentages, etc.) is just an additional feature that was thrown in on top of the functionality for accessing documents.

There are a variety of reporting products for Notes, and they are designed to do what you want.  You might want to look into them if you have a lot of similar requirements for a lot of different views.

There is also a way that you could do this with ReaderNames fields and an ID file that does have access to the database but doesn't have access to the documents.  Categories that are "empty" (i.e., contain no documents) will show up for a user, but this is a hack and not the right way to approach the problem. I really do not recommend it.  (It will probably only work for viewing anyhow.  I doubt an export will actually work in this setup, though I confess I've never tried it, and maybe it will.)

If this is just a one-off job, my suggestion would be to write an agent to collect the summary information that you want and either create summary documents in a folder, which you could then export and delete; or to have your agent directly write the data to Excel.